# jquery .map function executes twice

Tags: jquery

I use this function to load html into a page dynamically.

I call the function once but it runs twice. (I know that it runs twice because of the messages in the console.log).

Any idea on why it executes twice and how I can stop that?

```
function GetAjaxHTML() {
    $.map($(".AjaxContent"), function(el, i) {
        return $.ajax({ 
            url: '/ajax/' + $(el).prop("id").split("_")[0] + '/' + $(el).prop("id").split("_")[1],
            success: function(response) { 
                $(el).html(response); 
                console.log($(el).prop("id").split("_")[1] + ' loaded');
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Regards,
Dan

Comment: Might there be two elements of the '.AjaxContent on your page?

Comment: @MartinM There are 6 elements on the page but the mapping runs twice generating 12 ajax calls.

Comment: Have you called the GetAjaxHTML twice? Im gussing you already have solved this..

Comment: @MartinM Hi there. I only call the function once. I still haven't solved it.

Comment: Maybe you could make this without using the map function, and maybe you shouldn't return the entire ajax call. How about you bind the event in another way, and you don't return the ajax call, because you don't seem to use it.